# How to set the value of a global variable from within subscription

Tags: angular

I need to compare an email adress provided in a HTML form with an email adress i'm getting from a mock API. If the email adresses matches than it's enough for a successful authorization as for now. I've tried to archived this by creating a boolean variable `isAuthorized` in the `loginUser()` method, iv'e set its initial value to `false` and if the email adresses matches i'm trying to set it to `true` within the subscription of the http request but this does not work.

How do implement the authorization mentioned? I'm completely new at Angular.

**login.component.ts**

```
    import { Component, OnInit, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';

    import { LoginStateService } from 'src/app/login-state.service'    
    import { UserService } from '../user.service';
    import { HttpService } from '../http.service';

    interface Users {
      [key: string]: {
        email?: string;
      }
    }


    @Component({
      selector: 'app-login',
      templateUrl: './login.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
    })

    export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

      loginStateText: string;
      loginRout: string;

      constructor(
        private router: Router, 
        private user: UserService, 
        private loginState: LoginStateService, 
        private cssHelper: CssHelperService,
        private http: HttpService) { 
        }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.loginState.currentButtonText.subscribe(
          loginStateText => this.loginStateText = loginStateText
        );  
        this.loginState.currentRout.subscribe(
          loginRout => this.loginRout = loginRout
        ); 
      }

  loginUser(e){
    e.preventDefault;
    let email: string = e.target.elements[0].value;
    let isAuthorized: boolean = false;

    this.http.getUserId().subscribe(data => {  
    alert('Input: ' + email + '  /  JSON: ' + data[0].email);   
      if(email == data[0].email){
        console.log('Auth OK');
        isAuthorized = true;
      }
      else{
        console.log('Auth not OK');
      }
    })

    if(isAuthorized){
      this.user.setUserLoggedIn();
      this.loginState.ChangeLoginButtonText("Logout");
      this.loginState.ChangeLoginRout('/logout');
      alert("Authorization success");
      this.router.navigate(["/dashboard"]);
    }else{
      alert('Authorization failed, please check your credentials.')
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic should execute after getting data from server. Now the code is written wont wait for api request to complete.

Just move

```
if(isAuthorized){
  this.user.setUserLoggedIn();
  this.loginState.ChangeLoginButtonText("Logout");
  this.loginState.ChangeLoginRout('/logout');
  alert("Authorization success");
  this.router.navigate(["/dashboard"]);
}else{
  alert('Authorization failed, please check your credentials.')
}
```

into subscribe callback.

```
loginUser(e){
e.preventDefault;
let email: string = e.target.elements[0].value;
let isAuthorized: boolean = false;

this.http.getUserId().subscribe(data => {  
alert('Input: ' + email + '  /  JSON: ' + data[0].email);   
  if(email == data[0].email){
    console.log('Auth OK');
    isAuthorized = true;
  }
  else{
    console.log('Auth not OK');
  }

if(isAuthorized){ // here your logic should execute
  this.user.setUserLoggedIn();
  this.loginState.ChangeLoginButtonText("Logout");
  this.loginState.ChangeLoginRout('/logout');
  alert("Authorization success");
  this.router.navigate(["/dashboard"]);
}else{
  alert('Authorization failed, please check your credentials.')
}

})
```

}

Comment: I see thanks for the answer. However if i put this logic in the subscribe callback this.router.navigate(["/dashboard"]); dosn't work properly. I see the dashboard page for a second then i get thrown back to the login in page.